# iOS swift: swapping between two webviews

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller that has a webview whose content is injected. I want to be able to preload/prerender the content before displaying the webview.

My solution was to create two webviews instead and swap which one is displayed. How do i do that?

I tried swapping the reference to the second webview, remove the first from superview and add the second to the superview. But nothing is showing up

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pre-load your webviews, they need to be instantiated. If the webview isn't added to a parent view it may not load correctly. I would try keeping both webviews in the layout and just setting them hidden where appropriate. Setting them hidden will hide them from the user, but they will still behave as expected.